# htb with an inner gred how to setup filter to reach DPs

Tags: qos, tc, htb

I want to create a qos htb class and within this class there is a gred queue.

how do I add a working filter for each red queue in the gred queue?

what i tried was:

```
DEV=lo
SOMEGREDETTINGS="limit 60KB min 15KB max 45KB burst 20 avpkt 1000 bandwidth 1Mbit probability 0.02"

tc qdisc del dev $DEV root > /dev/null

tc qdisc add dev $DEV root handle 1:0 htb
tc class add dev $DEV parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 1Mbit ceil 1Mbit
tc class add dev $DEV parent 1:1  classid 1:10  htb rate 150Kbit ceil 1Mbit 
tc qdisc add dev $DEV parent 1:10 handle 110: gred setup DPs 3 default 2 grio

tc qdisc change dev $DEV parent 1:10 handle 110:1 gred $SOMEGREDETTINGS DP 0 prio 1
tc qdisc change dev $DEV parent 1:10 handle 110:2 gred $SOMEGREDETTINGS DP 1 prio 2
tc qdisc change dev $DEV parent 1:10 handle 110:3 gred $SOMEGREDETTINGS DP 2 prio 3


tc filter add dev $DEV parent 1:0  protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dport 5000 0xffff classid 1:1

tc filter add dev $DEV parent 1:1  protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dport 5000 0xffff classid 1:10

tc filter add dev $DEV parent 1:10  protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip dport 5000 0xffff flowid 110:3
```

i expect the port 5000 traffic to reach the DP 2 or 110:3 but actually it arrives in DP 0 or 110:1

how do I setup the filters in the right way to reach DP 2?